# Fetching a file passed through the intent-filter on API 29+

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file, android-external-storage, storage-access-framework

I have a working implementation for APIs <29 and am trying to migrate to the newest API.

AndroidManifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data
        android:host="*"
        android:mimeType="*/*"
        android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf"
        android:scheme="file" />
</intent-filter>
```

The activity gets called and I can access the file path via `getIntent().getData()`, but if I try to open an `InputStream` towards it, my access gets denied. I'm aware you're supposed to use the Storage Access Framework to let the user pick the document, but the examples in documentation all involve the app asking the user to open a certain file, rather than this case where the user opens a file via a file manager.

How can I get access to the file that the user wants to open with my app when targeting SDK 29?

Comment: Well start with showing the content scheme you receive. And then show the code where you try to open an input stream. Of course we think that your app is invoked from another app.

Comment: I get a "file" content scheme, as is defined in the AndroidManifest above. Input stream is nothing out of the ordinary:

`InputStream result = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`.

I get a FileNotFoundException due to permission issues.

Comment: As you should know apps cannot open files outside the apps private directories on Android.Q. You are also using an outdated filemanager. A suitable file manager should use its content provider to serve you files.  Probably the filemanager would use SAF to select files as filemanergers dont have acces to files anymore too on Q. And change your file scheme to content.

Comment: Let's take Gmail for an example. The user gets a file through the email, clicks on it and wants to open it with my app. How am I supposed to fetch that information, if not through the intent-filter?

Comment: Through the intent-filter. That is correct. You can keep the file scheme but add a content scheme. FIle schemes are out.

Comment: Adding a content scheme changed nothing. The app still receives a "file" scheme intent. If I remove the file scheme, my app doesn't get called at all from the file manager.

Comment: I also told you not to use that outdated filemanager. Of course that app will still send a file schema.

Comment: Well, the stock Samsung one also doesn't work, and it's the newest Android 9 one. Same goes with the LG one. I also tried to fetch the intent via Gmail attachment, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: You should give the comple content or file schemes if you talk about other apps.

Comment: Just remove the file scheme from the manifest. You do not need it. You dont need a content scheme there either. Try without the pathPattern first. I wonder which file manager you mean. Is it the same as when you use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE?

Comment: `If I remove the file scheme, my app doesn't get called at all from the file manager. ` Strange. Try other file managers. Please show the Gmail scheme when you removed the file scheme.

Comment: Gmail will give you a content:// scheme. Already in Android 6.

Comment: My main question is what is the content scheme even supposed to look like? I couldn't find any proper resources on this. I can't seem to get it to work with any of the apps, including Gmail.

Comment: Post the content scheme you get from Gmail. Did you remove the file scheme? And the path pattern?

Comment: I don't get the content scheme from Gmail because my app isn't even in the list for that particular file extension (so it cannot be opened through the email).

Comment: So you did not remove `android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf"
        android:scheme="file"`. Well....

Comment: I tried both leaving it as is, but also having only `android:scheme="content"` without any extra params.

Comment: You can drop the host attribute too.Leave only a minme type.

Comment: If I'm also dropping the `pathPattern`, how am I able to define which files to associate my app with?

Comment: Leave that for a moment... You first wanna get a Gmail content scheme. Well is your app in the list now?

Comment: It is not. On Galaxy S9+ I get a list of apps but mine is not on the list. On Pixel 2, I get the Google Drive "preview" where it says it's unable to preview, but when I download and try to open it, just says "can't open this file". It is a custom file extension (not .pdf as in this example), but I know it works since it can be opened directly through the app. I just can't get it to work via an external intent.